# Appending dataframes while creating a column for each dataframe in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of census files with xls extension for 6 states from 2012 to 2016 (30 files total) in one directory. I would like to create one dataframe appending all files, however, each file is lacking a year column. So I need to create while I am appending. Here is my code:

```
filesnames = os.listdir("/Census_Data")
dfs = list()
for filename in filesnames:
    for year in range(2012,2017):
         if filename.startswith("year"):
                 df = pd.read_excel(filename,sheet_name="Additional Measure Data",usecols={'Unnamed: 0', 'Unnamed: 1', 'Unnamed: 2', 'Demographics'})
                 df['year'] = year
         dfs.append(df)
```

The code returns the following table written over 30 times.

|  | Unnamed: 0 | Unnamed: 1 | Unnamed: 2 | Demographics | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | FIPS | State | County | Population | 2016 |
| 1 | 12000 | Florida | NaN | 19317568 | 2016 |
| 2 | 12001 | Florida | Alachua | 251417 | 2016 |
| 3 | 12003 | Florida | Baker | 27086 | 2016 |
| 4 | 12005 | Florida | Bay | 171903 | 2016 |
| 5 | 12007 | Florida | Bradford | 27049 | 2016 |

I am still not sure what the problem is. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the meaning of your question correctly, this code can help you :

```
#if thinks this is your list of dataframes
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

df = pd.concat(dfs)
```